# c# fail to get element in content page with getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I have posted the same question but I post it again since I haven't got any answers to that post yet.

I am trying to get some information (such as tagName, id using `GetElementsByTagName` method or `GetElementById` method) from a content page in a website using winforms.

[image]

as you see the pictures attached, no matter which selection you make (`select1`, `select2`, `select3` etc) web address stays same. however, contents under those selections are different in content page.

I am trying to access to a tagName(or id) from one of them(not selections but contents under a specific selection).

I have debugged and figured out(or seems like) I can not access to tagName(or id) from any of those contents under a specific selection.

It seems like I can only access tagName(or id) from main page. picture 3 will help better explanation of some terms such as main page, content page.

I tried to explain in detail, if my question seems still not clear, let me know plz.
My code looks like this.

```
var countGetFile = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("IFRAME");
foreach (HtmlElement l in countGetFile)
{
    if (l.GetAttribute("width").Equals("100%"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(l.GetAttribute("height").ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(l.GetAttribute("outerText").ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# get element information from content page in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51104583/c-sharp-get-element-information-from-content-page-in-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to grab information under 2 down level of #document from html.

html looks something like

```
...
    <src="..." id="A" ... >
    #document
        ...
        <src="..." id="B" ... >
        #document
            ...
            <span="C" ...>
            ...
```

I could grab span information (third curly brackets) with codes looking like

```
HtmlWindow frame1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("A").Document.Window.Frames["A"];

HtmlWindow frame2 = frame1.Document.GetElementById("B").Document.Window.Frames["B"];


foreach (HtmlElement elm in frame2.Document.All)
{
    if (elm.GetAttribute("tagName").Equals("C"))
    {
        // your command             
    }
}
```

to use Document.Window.Frames you need a header using "System.Collections";

btw, there is a problem. When I try to access to the information in third curly bracket, I need to do some kinds of work between `frame1` and `frame2` such as delaying for `frame2` to have enough time to be able to access to next level after `frame1`.

I figured a kind of hack to get it through. Place a messagebox to pop up for short time delay, or place a delay function( not freeze ) with async code looking like,

```
async Task PutTaskDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);//5 secs
}
```

I just found a temporary solution for accessing to second level. I will appreciate anyone who knows some ways to solve this problem.

Comment: you might not need "System.Collections" to use Document.Window.Frames